# Draw border between rows and cols of table

Tags: asp.net, html-table, border, rows

How to draw a border between rows and cols of the asp.net(C#) table?

I have following:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" 
        BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black">
    </asp:Table>
```

in the codebehind file I add rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < games.Count(); i++)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    tc.Text = games[i].getData(j);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }
                tr.BorderWidth = 1;
                tr.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
```

However, I I don't see any border between rows and cols of the table.
The table is:

[image]

So, how to draw borders between rows and cols of the asp.net table?

Answer (score 6):

You are missing two attributes

```
GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid"
```

Should be

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" 
    BorderWidth="1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid">
```

CSS styling is better though

Comment: For css styling you can use:  #Table1
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}

#Table1, td, th #Table1
{
border:1px solid black;
}

Answer (score 3):

I would just use CSS to draw the borders:

```
#table1 {
  border: solid thin black;
}

#table1 td {
  border: solid thin black;
}
```

Also, creating a table via code is BAD!  You should look into using the Repeater control.